# Какой тип верстки адаптивного сайта актуален в 2017 году?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap, адаптивная-верстка

Здравствуйте. Только недавно познакомился с Bootstrap и мне, если честно, не очень понравилась верстка с ним. Иногда бывают запары, блоки не влазят и т.п. Плюс посмотрел некоторые видео, где советуют использовать Flex верстку по Flex-box и препроцессорам SCSS и LESS и там все выглядело просто шикарно - все блоки встают на своё место и нету запар с вертикальным выравниванием.

Хочу узнать, что по этому поводу думают опытные верстальщики и стоит ли забить на Bootstrap и сразу переходить на flex-box + SCSS и LESS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

За все время работы с bootstrap не возникало проблем с размещением блоков. Думаю, что стоит подробнее ознакомиться с документацией bootstrap.

Также советую ознакомиться с примерами верстки блоков с bootstrap [здесь](https://blackrockdigital.github.io/startbootstrap-3-col-portfolio/)

> Bootstrap is the undisputed leader among the available frameworks today.

Вам будет легче всего работать над проектами и освоить верстку именно на нем. Более того, большинство разработчик и веб дизайнеров используют именно bootstrap. Sitepoint сообщает следующий рейтинг фреймворков:

1)Bootstrap

2)Foundation by Zurb

3)Semantic UI

4)Pure by Yahoo

5)UIkit by YOOtheme

Comment: Кроме того, bootstrap 4 (который в данный момент в альфа версии) будет как раз на flex.